# cat file.txt VS. cat < file.txt

Tags: linux, bash

Salve pessoal,

Comecei recentemente a estudar o bash Unix e estou com uma dúvida que não consigo sanar a respeito do comando "cat".

Durante o curso da Code Academy, ele apresenta o código em dois momentos:

cat file.txt

cat < file.txt

Depois de muito procurar, eu vi alguns sites e explicações que dizem que o segundo exemplo não passa o arquivo para leitura. Ele passa o conteúdo do arquivo como *input* padrão (*Standard Input*).

Eu não estou conseguindo entender qual seria a utilidade desse comando utilizando o operador "<".

Como vocês usam/usariam esse comando "cat < file.txt"?

Links que usei: 
https://www.tecmint.com/13-basic-cat-command-examples-in-linux/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258931/difference-between-cat-and-cat

Comment: [A resposta do **Unix & Linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258932/124426) não foi suficiente pra esclarecer a dúvida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando `cat file.txt` simplesmente lê o arquivo e o exibe na tela, ou mais precisamente exibe no `stdout`, nem sempre vai ser uma tela, no seu caso atual sim, já que esta usando terminal, mas `stdout` não se refere a tela e sim a a saída de um programa, o terminal exibir o resultado é "consequencia"

O operador `<` lê o arquivo (sem precisar do `cat`) e o joga para "algum lugar", ou seja passa o `stdin` do comando anterior, no caso ao fazer isto `cat < file.txt` o `< file.txt` já esta lendo o arquivo e passando o conteudo para o `stdin` do `cat` e o `cat` por sua vez devolve para o `stdout` (que no seu caso vai exibir diretamente na tela)

Para resumir então:

1. Primeiro caso `cat file.txt` lê o arquivo e envia ao stdout
2. Segudo caso `cat < file.txt`

   O `<` pega o conteudo do arquivo e adiciona ao stdin do `cat` e em seguida o `cat` como não recebeu parametro para leitura de um arquivo mas recebeu o `stdin` então devolve o proprio `stdin` para o output

---

> Como vocês usam/usariam esse comando "cat < file.txt"?

Basicamente esse comando não vai servir de nada, é sério, não da forma que esta, isto é apenas para você entender o comportamento do `<`, já que o `cat` consegue trabalhar tanto com parâmetros como ler 2 arquivos e exibi-los no `stdout`:

```
cat foo.txt bar.txt
```

Quanto lêr um stdin, por exemplo se passar qualquer texto no `stdin` do `cat` ele vai exibir o que digitou logo após o Enter ou após o Ctrl+D (2 vezes, isso digo no terminal), faça isso (se o $ é apenas para ilustrar):

```
$ cat
```

Então digite:

```
Ola mundo!
```

E aperte o Enter e será exibido diretamente o que estava digitando:

> [image: resultado]
>
> O primeiro "ola mundo" era aonde eu podia digitar, o segundo é apenas exibido e eu não posso manipular diretamente ele

Ou seja, na pratica esses exemplos são apenas para entender o comportamento do `stdin` de cada programa, entenda que o `stdin` não se refere ao `stdin` do terminal, mas de qualquer programa que vá executar, pois cada programa tem o seu próprio fluxo (stdin, stdout, etc)

Comment: Agora entendi certinho o lance do stdin e stdout. Muito obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme.